# select current month from manually filled combobox

Tags: vb.net

```
 Me.drpmonth.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
        Me.drpmonth.FormattingEnabled = True
        Me.drpmonth.Items.AddRange(New Object() {"JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"})
        Me.drpmonth.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(886, 28)
        Me.drpmonth.Name = "drpmonth"
        Me.drpmonth.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 21)
        Me.drpmonth.TabIndex = 9
```

Manually i filled the combobox as shown above ..While form loading current month should be selected from that combobox , how it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Me.drpmonth.SelectedIndex = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() - 1
```